# is some of matrice with it's transpose positive definite? when eigenvalues of matrix is positive

Tags: matrices

Suppose M = A+ A^T , and we know that all of eigenvalues of A are real and positive, is M positive definite? or semi positive definite?

Comment: Are all entries of $A$ real?

Comment: yes all of the elements are real

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do you have sth in mind?

Answer (score 4):

Consider
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-4\\
0 &1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then all of eigenvalues of $A$ are real and positive, but $M$ is indefinite.